# Add LayoutParams to XML defined view To turn Screen On

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to add a LayoutParam (FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)  to a view that I have defined via XML.

EDIT: This is a window flag WindowManager.LayoutParams.

Would I do this in the xml as well, or is there a way to add the params to the view before i call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_view);
```

UPDATE: Apparently this was not the easiest way to go about waking up the phone. Check the accepted answer about using the PowerManger to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

before you call your `setContentView` method.

**Alternatively**, try using the [`PowerManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) class.  Make sure you request the proper `WAKE_LOCK` [permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
//   ..screen will stay on during this section..
wl.release();
```

Comment: What was the error? Does it work if you use this syntax `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);`?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't wake the screen like I would expect it.

Comment: PowerManger was the way to go. Although I did have to add the ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP flag because I was literally trying to wake it up

Answer (score 0):

If you need to turn on screen and wake up you phone dismiss keyguard for example, you can use this in `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` class:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```